# Cannot read property of data null react

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I'm having some trouble with my api, every time I login and land on my `Dashboard page` the data it return `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null`.
Its a simple app using JWT authentication to login, which means I'm required to set the token in locale storage on login, I've done that. However the token expires after 15 mins and requires a refresh token. Here are the details on the api:

```
Retrieve the necessary data for the dashboard at 'https://freddy.codesubmit.io/dashboard'. 
This endpoint requires a 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' header. 
Use the access token that you retrieved from Login. 
Keep in mind that access tokens expire after 15 minutes. 
You may request a fresh access token by sending a POST request to https://freddy.codesubmit.io/refresh' with the 'Authorization: Bearer refresh_token' header.
```

I haven't done the refresh token part yet as I'm not sure how to, I assume that may be the problem? Its timing out because the token is expired?

Here is my login:

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import { AuthContext } from '../hooks/UserContext';
import Logo from '../images/Freddys_Logo.svg';
import '../css/Login.css';
  
const Login = () => {
  const [userError, setUserError] = useState("");
  const [passError, setPassError] = useState("");
  const {setLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
  let history = useHistory();
  const [authInfo, setAuthInfo] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: ""
  })

  const handleChange = e => {
    setAuthInfo({
      ...authInfo,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('https://freddy.codesubmit.io/login', authInfo)
      .then(res => {
        setLoggedIn(true);
         localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.access_token);
         localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", res.data.refresh_token);
         history.push('/dashboard')
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

 return (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <div className="logoContainer">
    <div className="heading">
       <p>
         Freddy's
         <br/>
        Artisanal
        <br/>
        Halloween
        <br/>
        Candy Shop
       </p>
    </div>
      <div className="svgLogo">
        <img src={Logo} className="svgLogo" alt="image" />  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="inputContainer">
    <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input 
        name="username" 
        type="text" 
        value={authInfo.username} 
        placeholder="username" 
        onChange={handleChange} 
        className="input" 
      />
      <input 
        name="password" 
        type="password" 
        value={authInfo.password} 
        placeholder="************" 
        onChange={handleChange}  
        className="input" 
      />
      <input 
        type="submit"  
        value="Login" 
        className="submitButton"
      />
    </form>
    </div>
    ElmStreet2019
  </div>
 )
}

export default Login;
```

Here is my api I'm using to grab my data: useFetch.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const useFetch = async => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          "https://freddy.codesubmit.io/dashboard"
        , {headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}});

        setResponse(res);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error, "err");
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [token]);
  return { response, error };
};
export default useFetch;
```

Here is the page I'm trying to display my data on: Dashboard.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import Layout from './Layout';
import Table from './Table';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from '../hooks/UserContext'
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import Switch from "react-switch";
import BarChart from 'react-bar-chart';

import '../css/Dashboard.css'

const Dashboard = () => {
  const {} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { response, error } = useFetch();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token")


  const handleCheckedChange = () => {
    setChecked(!checked)
  }

  const lastSevenDays = [
    {text: 'yesterday', value: 500}, 
    {text: 'today', value: 1300},
    {text: 'day 3', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 4', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 5', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 6', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 7', value: 300}, 
  ];
  const lastTwelveMonths = [
    {text: 'this month', value: 500}, 
    {text: 'today', value: 1300},
    {text: 'day 3', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 4', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 5', value: 300},
    {text: 'day 6', value: 300}, 
    {text: 'day 7', value: 300}, 
  ];
  const margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};

  console.log(error)

 return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="item">
            <span className="textStyle">Today</span>
            <p>$1456 / 9 orders</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <span className="textStyle">Today</span>
            <p>$1456 / 9 orders</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <span className="textStyle">Today</span>
            <p>$1456 / 9 orders</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="revenueContainer">
          <div className="title">
          {!checked ? <h2>Revenue (last 7 days)</h2> : <h2>Revenue (last 12 months)</h2>}
          </div>
          <div className="toggle">
            <Switch 
              onChange={handleCheckedChange} 
              checked={checked} 
              onColor="#86d3ff"
              onHandleColor="#2693e6"
              uncheckedIcon={false}
              checkedIcon={true}
              boxShadow="0px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)"
              activeBoxShadow="0px 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div style={{width: '100%'}}> 
            {!checked ? (
              <BarChart 
                ylabel=''
                width={600}
                height={300}
                margin={margin}
                data={lastSevenDays}
              />
              ) : !!checked ? (
                <BarChart 
                ylabel=''
                width={600}
                height={300}
                margin={margin}
                data={lastTwelveMonths}
              />
              ) : null}
            </div>
          </div>

        <h2>Bestsellers</h2>
        <Table bestsellers={response.data.dashboard.bestsellers} /> 
    </Layout>
 )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Table component in Dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/Table.css';

const Table = ({bestsellers}) => {
  if(bestsellers === undefined || null) {
    return <div> loading...</div>
  }
  return (
    <div className="tableContainer">
      <div className="headingContainer">
        <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading">Product Name</span></div>
          <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading">Price</span></div>
          <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading"># Units Sold</span></div>
          <div className="tableHeader"><span className="tableHeading">Revenue</span></div>
      </div>
      {bestsellers
         .slice(0, 3)
         .map(row => (
        <div className="rowContainer" key={row.product.id}> 
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">{row.product.name}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">N/A</span>
          </div>
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">{row.units}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="tableItem">
            <span className="tableItemText">{row.revenue}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useFetch` hook initially returns `null` as `response`. In `Dashboard` component, you're trying to pass `response.data.dashboard.bestsellers` to `Table` component without checking if `response` is not `null`/`undefined`.

Depending on how modern your development environment is, you could write:

```
<Table bestsellers={response && response.data.dashboard.bestsellers} />
```

or:

```
<Table bestsellers={response?.data.dashboard.bestsellers} />
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one did the trick for me